# Event loop flow with Async/Await

Tags: javascript, debugging, async-await, visual-studio-code

I have been experimenting with Async/Await commands in Javascript and noticed something I'm confused about.

When I run the following code in Visual Studio Code in debug mode, after I get to the first 'await' line of code it jumps to the end of the function and then continues sequentially through the rest of the code including other 'await' lines.  Why is this?

```
const axios = require("axios");
const apiURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'

async function multipleRequestsAsync() {
  try {
    console.log("starting...")
    const response1 = await axios.get(apiURL);
    console.log(response1.data);
    const response2 = await axios.get(apiURL);
    console.log(response2.data);
    const response3 = await axios.get(apiURL);
    console.log(response3.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

multipleRequestsAsync();
```

Here is the [code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afrankel/r7qkggsv/).

Here is an animated gif of what I'm talking about. 
[image]

Comment: At a guess, it's showing that the function has returned a promise at this point

Comment: Are you using a transpiler?

Comment: @Bergi - no I'm not using a transpiler.  I don't have another way besides Visual Studio code to debug it to see if it's just visual studio code.

Comment: @Jaromanda X - perhaps, although I would have thought either all calls with 'await' statements fall to the end of the function first before continuing or none of them do that...not just the first 'await' statement.

Comment: no, that makes no sense, a function can only return a single value - in the case of an async function, it returns a promise at the point where the first await is called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably signifies the point at which the function returns the promise. If you include some other code after the call to your `async function`, that would be stepped through before the execution continues after the `await` in a future turn of the event loop. Consider

```
async function multipleRequestsAsync() {
  try {
    console.log("starting...");                // 3
    const response1 = await axios.get(apiURL); // 4
    console.log("done");                       // 7
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}                                              // 5

console.log("before start");                   // 1
const promise = multipleRequestsAsync();       // 2
console.log("continuing...");                  // 6
```

You'd get the output

```
before start
starting...
continuing
// later:
done
```

The breakpoint at the end of the function (5) would occur between leaving the function at `await` (4) and the statement after the call (6).

Comment: So are you saying that if there was a repeated (4) and (7) line right after (4)/(7) (like in my example) you wouldn't see it go to (5) after the secondary repeated (4)...just after the first await call?  If so, why is that?

Comment: @ArthurFrankel Yes, that's what your gif shows, right? The function returns a promise only once.